# Combining multiple jquery files

Tags: php, jquery, compression

For some reason I can't combine my javascript files in one single file through php, like I can with css.

Basicly I wish to combine all of my javascript files into one. However that breaks my code somehow. It's like the $-value which jQuery generates isn't available through the rest of the code (such as jquery ui).

Does the jQuery need to be loaded in it's own `<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>` for some reason? And what is that reason then?

I include them in the same order that they work in the browser.

jQuery -> jQuery UI -> jQuery custom functions -> my own script

Comment: In what order are you combining them?

Comment: I had this problem once with 1.7.3 and it had something to do with the way they had commenting structured at the beginning/end of the minified scripts. Either code was being commented out or comments were being coded in. It was an easy fix. Just view your source and look at what's happening at the beginning/end of each script.

Comment: You might be on to something. My jQuery ends on `{var a=this.pushStack(this,"after"` for some reason, but yet works on it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to put a new-line and/or semicolon between the single scripts.
E.g. the minified jquery ui script you get from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js ends with

```
return this}})}(jQuery)
```

If you now append another script right behind that you will most likely get a syntax error.
Lets take a crude scripts.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: Application/javascript');
readfile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
readfile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js');

echo '$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hello");
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
';
```

this won't work, but

```
<?php
header('Content-type: Application/javascript');
readfile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
echo "\r\n;";
readfile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js');
echo "\r\n;";    
echo '$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hello");
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
';
```

will.

Other things to consider:

- this is probably not a silver bullet. I chose "\r\n;" to a) escape from a // comment in the last line and b) to close an "open" statement with the semi-colon. But the missing-semicolon behaviour of javascript (and the implementations of it) can be rather odd (it's a bad feature) and I'd rather "fix" each individual script manually than adding a fixed "repair string".
- I'm stronlgy in the "let a cdn like google host those javascript libraries and rely on the client's cache" camp  ...but without good evidence at hand to support that position.

Comment: I will look this up soon enough. Nice solution. Personally I've sometimes had problems with "let a cdn like google host those javascript libraries" because in rare cases lag on those sites slows my own site down, and I had a case where my anti virus program blocked javascript from google url.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid point. I dislike those sites that hang because some (in my case useless) facebook api thingy can't be retrieved :-/ Haven't noticed it on the googleapi cdn yet though - again with the disclaimer: without any extensive research.

Comment: Apart from that it's nice to host on google since their servers are fast and the browsers needs less files to cache (if all use it), which also speeds things up. Too bad my anti virus porgram resented that solution.

Comment: I fetched a new jQuery and tried this solution. It worked perfect! Thanks!